# Seconds has/have passed

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verbs

Which is proper?

> The method will be fired after the specified duration of seconds *has* passed.

OR

> The method will be fired after the specified duration of seconds *have* passed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A duration *has* passed, but seconds *have* passed. In the phrase "a duration of seconds", the noun is "duration", so the correct verb is *has*.

Answer (score 3):

"Has passed" is grammatically correct, but sounds unnatural to me. I would prefer.

> The method will be fired after the specified *number* of seconds has passed.

The user is not actually specifying a duration, but a number which is interpreted as a duration.

Answer (score 2):

The subject of the sentence is *duration*, not seconds, so the verb has to be conjugated with it (*has passed*)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, this formulation would be correct, too.

> The method will be fired after the specified time has passed.

Answer (score 0):

The rule of "Error of Proximity" in Agreement of Subject with the verb applies here.
The subject is 'duration' and not 'seconds' although the latter is placed closer to the verb in the sentence.
As a singular subject takes a singular verb, 'has' will be a correctly used verb here, for the singular subject 'duration'. In other words, 'duration has' while 'seconds have' would be correct.

Comment: Include links to sources/references

Comment: I couldn't have said it any more obscurely myself!

Comment: I will try to expand my explanation.The Errors due to Proximity state that there is an erroneous tendency among students to make the verb agree in number with a noun near it,instead of its proper subject.When one is confused, ,one must make sure of the Subject of the verb.